# java regex pattern.compile Vs matcher

Tags: regex, java.util.scanner

Im trying to find whether a word contains consecutive identical strings or not, using java.regex.patterns, while testing an regex with matcher, It returns true. But if I only use like this :
    `System.out.println("test:" + scanner.hasNext(Pattern.compile("(a-z)\\1")));`
 it returns false.

```
public static void test2() {
String[] strings = { "Dauresselam", "slab", "fuss", "boolean", "clap", "tellme" };

String regex = "([a-z])\\1";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
for (String string : strings) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
}
```

this returns true. which one is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern `([a-z])\\1` uses a capturing group to match a single lowercase character which is then followed by a backreference to what is captured in group 1.

Ih you have `Dauresselam` for example, it would match the first `s` in the capturing group and then matches the second `s`. So if you want to match consecutive characters you could use that pattern.

The pattern `(a-z)\\1` uses a capturing group to match `a-z` literally and then then uses a backreference to what is captured in group 1. So that would match `a-za-z`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want. Here you use parenthesis:

```
Pattern.compile("(a-z)\\1").
```

Here you use Square brackets inside pareanthesis:

```
String regex = "([a-z])\\1";
```

To compare, you should obviously use the same pattern.

Comment: thank you.. could you tell me the difference between compile and matcher